# Open page in WebView by clicking on an external link

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a website that has a web version and a webview. It is necessary to open directly in the app (if installed) the link to recover password that the user receives in his email.

After adding the code below to AndroidManifest.xml, I was able to open the app by clicking on the link.

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="*" android:scheme="myapp"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Link I created to test:

```
<a href="myapp://www.site.com/password-reset/token/abc123">Click</a>
```

However, it always opens the home page in the app, instead of opening the specific page in the link.

Do I need to make any further modifications to the app to interpret this type of link?

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.site.app");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }
   });
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    
    if (data != null && data.toString().startsWith("myapp:")) {
        urlIntent = data.toString().replace("myapp", "https");
    } else {
        urlIntent = "https://www.site.app";
    }

    webView.loadUrl(urlIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Deeplinks` normally just triggers the app to be opened, they don't help you navigate or open a specific location unless you define `Fragment` or `Activity` based `intent-filters` or manually handle.

You should get the data which includes `URL` from `intent` first then give it to `WebView` as a `URL`. You can do that inside either `onNewIntent` or `onCreate` methods like so;

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    val uri = intent.data
}
```

then load it in `WebView` like;

```
webview.loadUrl(uri.toString())
```

Comment: I put inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() or onPageFinished() ? I edited my post and put the mainActivity.

Comment: @DiegoVieira hereinafter you can access to `Intent` by calling `getIntent()` in `onCreate`. Then get data by calling `getIntent().getData();`

After all, pass data to `WebView` to load the page like so; `webview.loadUrl(data.toString());`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it's working! I just needed to make a treatment in the url. I put the solution in my post.

Comment: @DiegoVieira glad to hear that is working for you! Thanks for the upvote, too!